# Perl, Command not found after entering "perl -v"

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl.
Running Fedora 16
I have installed Perl recently, after the installation, I checked via "perl -v",
I got the following lines:

```
/usr/bin/perl: line 19: use: command not found
/usr/bin/perl: line 20: use: command not found
/usr/bin/perl: line 23: my: command not found
/usr/bin/perl: line 24: my: command not found
/usr/bin/perl: line 25: my: command not found
/usr/bin/perl: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/perl: line 28: `my %list=();'
```

Can I know why is it so?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your /usr/bin/perl an actual perl script that could be getting interpreted by the OS as a shell script? That's what the output looks like, but that's... odd. How did you install Perl?

Comment: How did you install Perl? From RPM? Which RPMs? What does `which perl` say? What does `head \`which perl\`` say?

Comment: Why did you need to install Perl? The standard Fedora 16 installation include Perl 5.14.2.

Comment: For the command "perl -v" if its not installed properly it would say "perl is not recognosed as a internal or external command" . i suppose you are trying to run some script, can u post the complete script?

Answer (score 4):

That output is the output of a Perl script being executed by a bourne shell instead of `perl`.

`perl` is very funky on your setup. Maybe it has been accidentally replaced? Maybe you have an alias named `perl`? (What does `type perl` output?)

Comment: Forgot about type. Always thought there was just which as in which perl.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, heh. I just added when I noticed some atrocious grammar mistakes in my post. `type` is a bash builtin that provides more info than `which` since it knows about the shell's aliases and such.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.

Finally it was some so silly as that I had a blank space before the first line: #!/usr/bin/perl

Then, that line was ignored and the script was being interpreted by bash insted by perl.

I hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very surprised if there is a unix-like system which ships without perl. I'm not surprised that there are problems if more than one version are installed over each other.

If you have to use that system and can't start over, try installing it in some other location like /opt

Answer (score 0):

Does #!/usr/bin/perl exists in your script at the begining? 
I think its trying to run the script through the shell instead of perl, Check whether the script is using the  encoding character UTF8 and finally try to invoke perl explicitly using the command **perl filename**.
Try to login with ROOT and try the same

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command

**which perl**

You should get output as ***/usr/bin/perl***